# SonarQube ignore (sonar.issue.ignore.allfile) @Entity files

Tags: jpa, sonarqube

I'm trying to get SonarQube (6.3.1) to exclude all JPA Entity-related classes using the `sonar.issue.ignore.allfile` option.

I've set this parameter using the SonarQube web interface:
[image]

*(Note - I'm using @Column rather than @Entity since all the affected classes contain @Column annotations, but not all of them are top-level @Entity classes)*

However, SonarQube still analyses the classes I'm trying to ignore and flags them as having high duplication. My goal is to have them be completely excluded from all checks - duplication, code smells, test coverage, etc.

I've looked at the SonarQube [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) for this attribute, and can't see where I'm going wrong. Any ideas?

```
package com.example;

import javax.persistence.*;

public class BWDetails {

    @Column(name="ENTITY_NO")
    private Long entityNo;

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;
    //----snip------
}
```

Comment: More info: 
I have considered moving these files into a designated package and ignoring them using {sonar.coverage.exclusions} / {sonar.cpd.exclusions} / {sonar.global.exclusions} but I can't actually change the package structure, and I don't want to use these folder-based exclusions since they will apply to unrelated files which should be analysed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exclusions you've set up are Issue exclusions, and as such only turn off issues.

To ignore the files altogether, you'll need to list them in the Files section of the exclusions page, particularly in the `sonar.exclusions` field. Note that this field accepts 1) multiple values 2) patterns, so if these files have a common element in the class name that may be a way to handle this without exhaustively listing every single file to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks - so to be clear: in SQ terminology, code duplication is not a type of Issue and that's why the Issue exclusion I've set up (sonar.issue.ignore.allfile) is not having an effect?

Comment: Exactly @johnd.